# IISReset fails on local server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm having an issue with running the iisreset command while logged in to the server that is a local admin on the box. I'm logged in via RDP to servers, running an elevated powershell or command prompt, and trying to run the command and it is telling me "access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this command..." I can do anything else on this server, including opening up IIS and restarting services through there. Event viewer, services console, everything else. What am I not understanding about the iisreset command?

Answer (score 0):

For this instance, it appears that there was some change to a GPO that changed the "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrator in Admin Approval Mode" from "Prompt for consent" to "Prompt for consent on the secure desktop." Changing it back fixed it for me.